# Import photo once from XML

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

I want to make a .swf that imports a jpg from a remote server.
I'm able to do that with this code (actionscript 2):

```
var my_xml = new XML();
var url = new String;

my_xml.load("http://www.someURL.com/xml.php");
my_xml.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
    //trace(this);
    }
    url = this;
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+this+"/picture?type=large";
    picLoad.loadMovie(url);
    trace(url);

}
```

After the jpg is shown, I want it to make some actions in a repeat. The thing is that every time the movie clip repeats, it needs to extract the jpg again, thus making a delay of 0.5 sec or so.

How can I make it get the jpg once so it won't delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just cache the result of the loading operation? Actually, based on your code, you could simply use a boolean to tell you whether you should load the picture again or not.

Something like that should work:

```
var my_xml = new XML();
var url = new String;
var pictureLoaded = false;

my_xml.load("http://www.someURL.com/xml.php");
my_xml.onLoad = function(success){
if (success){
    if (pictureLoaded) return;

    url = this;
    url = "https://graph.facebook.com/"+this+"/picture?type=large";
    picLoad.loadMovie(url);
    pictureLoaded = true;
    trace(url);

}
```